# Why does the curvature change with respect to the sign of the wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, curvature

In quantum mechanics, in the context of studying unidimensional potentials, we studied this case of potential

[image: Potential]

And to analise the possible looks of the wave function $\phi$, we divided in 3 regions, let's consider only the region $V_0<E<V_+$ with such energy. Now we can take an example of an energy $E_0$ and try to find how will the wave function look like, remembering that it has to satisfy Schroedinger's equation, somehow, my teacher finds out that $\phi''(x)>0$ for $\phi(x)>0$ and $\phi''(x)<0$ for $\phi(x)<0$, how? Like I have always thought the curvature of a function didn't change wrt to if the function is positive or negative. Also apparently that was for "allowed" regions (for $E>V(x)$, but we also have "prohibited" regions (for $E<V(x)$) in which now actually $\phi''$ and $\phi$ have opposite signs while that for allowed regions they have the same sign, why?

Also I have drawn another picture that may help visualise:

[image: Seco d Picture]

Comment: $$E\psi=-\frac{\hslash^2}{2m}\psi^{\prime\prime}+V(x)\psi\qquad\implies\qquad\psi^{\prime\prime}=\frac{2m}{\hslash^2}\left[V(x)-E\right]\psi$$the form on the RHS makes it clear that it is really just the Schrödinger's Equation on the LHS that is giving you this behaviour. This argument is actually rather useful.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent but doesn't this imply that if $E>V(x)$ we get that $\psi''$ and $\psi$ will have opposite signs and not equal signs as my teacher said?

Comment: I think you likely misremembered what your teacher said. Or your teacher had a mental typo at the time. You can see that my equations are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the curvature is varying based on the sign of the second derivative.

$\kappa=\frac{y''}{(1+y'^2)^{3/2}}$ The sign of the curvature is the sign of the second derivative.

So if you have $\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}+V\psi=E\psi$

then $\frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2}=\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}(V-E)\psi$

So if $V>E$, curvature is positive and solutions are roughly exponential decay/grow, and potentially bounded states. If $V<E$ then you have negative curvature, sinusoids, and/or scattering states.